# Odoo Currency conversion

Tags: currency, odoo-13

These are the fields in my import_payment.py

```
transaction_date = fields.Date(string="Transaction Date",
                               required=True)
facts_id = fields.Char(string="Student ID",
                       required=True)
paid_in_lei = fields.Float(string="Amount Paid in LEI")
paid_in_euro = fields.Float(string="Amount Paid in EURO")
amount = fields.Float(string="Amount")
error_msg = fields.Char(string="Error Msg")
invoice_number = fields.Char(string="Invoice No")
invoice_id = fields.Many2one(string="Invoice",
                             comodel_name="account.move")
payment_id = fields.Many2one(string="Payment",
                             comodel_name="account.payment")
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', default=lambda self: self.env.company.id)
currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', related='company_id.currency_id', readonly=True, store=True)
```

Can somebody help me to convert the "**paid_in_euro**" field based on the "**exchange rate**" of the "**transaction_date**" and insert it to "**amount**" field in "**RON(Base currency)**"

Sorry I am new at Odoo. Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use odoo's currency conversion function

```
from_currency._convert(from_amount, to_currency, company, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all convert your **`amount`** field into **`compute`** field like and make it dependable on **`paid_in_euro`**

```
amount = fields.Float(string="Amount", compute='_amount_in_base')

@api.depends('paid_in_euro')
def _amount_in_base(self):
    if self.paid_in_euro:
        amount_convert = company_currency.with_context(date=self.date).compute(self.paid_in_euro, convert_currency)
```

Comment: I'm sorry sir but I can't understand this part: "amount_convert = company_currency.with_context(date=self.date).compute(self.paid_in_euro, convert_currency)". I have updated my question I would very much appreciate if you could answer my questions using the details above.

Comment: I get an error "Unresolved reference convert_currency"